# Compare a file with stdout and print out not match line

Tags: bash

Compare file.txt

```
cat file.txt
apache2 php7.4 mysql-server
```

to the output of

```
dpkg --get-selections
```

Any package that are not matched the content of file.txt, paste them as the argument of "apt remove"

How can I do it in a single command line? Please.

Comment: See [Linux tools to treat files as sets and perform set operations on them](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/11343)

Answer (score 0):

It will most probably break your system, but you asked for it:

```
dpkg --get-selections | cut -f 1 | grep -v -x -f <( cat file.txt | xargs -n 1) | xargs apt -y remove
```

This will remove the packages from `file.txt` from the list fetched from `dpkg --get-selections` (which are all not matching file.txt) and send them to `apt remove`

Derived from the comment another possible solution, which lets you interact with `apt`:

```
apt remove $( dpkg --get-selections | cut -f 1 | grep -v -x -f <( cat file.txt | xargs -n 1) )
```

Comment: Piping into `xargs apt remove` is sub-optimal as xargs consumes stdin, so `apt` and child processes can not receive kbd input (i.e. the user's answers to apt, dpkg, debconf, etc questions). Instead, use xargs' `-a` option and process subst or, better yet, refactor to use command subst. e.g. I often use commands like the following to remove old kernel packages that I no longer need: `apt-get purge $(dlocate -k | grep -E '5.16.0-3|5.1[45]')`. xargs isn't needed unless you're going to exceed $ARG_MAX (which is extremely unlikely, you'd need well over a hundred thousand pkg names as args).

Comment: It doesn't matter, because it will anyway break his system.

Comment: that depends on what's in their `file.txt`.  and it does matter because if you're going to do something you should at least make an effort to do it right.